# Consensus Clustering Plus in R

Tags: cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, consensus

I've got a dilemma on deciding an optimal number of cluster from my dataset.
I have obtained ConsensusClusterPlus heatmap plots but not really sure on deciding on the optimal number of clusters.

Can anyone help in this? I've attached pictures of heatmaps and plots to decide on optimal number of clusters. Seems like k=3 is an optimal number click here to see pics pic [6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lGkk.png), pic [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xX2sN.png), pic [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xytTf.png), pic [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFyQY.png), pic [7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4We2m.png), pic [8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SZRU.png), pic [9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlXuZ.png), pic [10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTVMs.png)

Comment: probably wrong place for the question...

Answer (score 1):

*Note, I'm not that specialized in this topic, but currently I'm also working with cluster ensembles. So, take my arguments with caution.*

Based on the images (2:7) the heatmap shows a 2-block structure, giving a slight hint of *k*=2. Going further with picture 9, the elbow similarly suggests the same *k*, since after two there is a very sparse decrease in change of the AUC.

In addition, in case you haven't read it, see the paper of Monti, Tamayo, Mesirov and Golub (2003) https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1023949509487 Using heatmap aswell. However, also take note with the weakness surrounding a heatmap, such as deriving clusters from data while there appears to be none, see Șenbabaoğlu et al. (2014) http://www.nature.com/articles/srep06207.

I assume you already found an answer, so please share your argument if possible, as clustering is often underpinned as a subjective type of class discovery in ML.